# Looped ajax only submits sometimes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am working on a dynamic page with multiple forms that can be added and removed by the user. My jquery script goes and finds all 'form' elements and submits them with jquerys ajax method. Here is the script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
(function (){
    var id = $(document).data('campaign_id');
    $(document).on('click', '#save-button', function () {
        $('form').each(function (){
            var data = new FormData(this);
            var form = $(this);
            if(!form.parent().hasClass('hideme'))
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url: form.attr('action'),
                    type: 'POST',
                    data:  data,
                    mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData:false,
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                    {
                        console.log('form submitted '+count);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        window.location.replace('/campaign');
    });
})(); //end SIAF
});//end document.ready
```

The problem occurs that only sometimes the form submits, I can get it to if I click the save button a few times or if I remove the window.location.redirect that runs at the end, I suspect it is something to do with the redirect occurring before the submit, but I am not sure of a solution after going through some of the documentation

Comment: Well, what's the point of the `window.location.replace('/campaign');`? Why are you trying to redirect at the same time as sending the AJAX requests?

Comment: ajax is asynchronous, your `window.replace` will fire before first form is even completed

Comment: $.when will help with this case.

Comment: OR, since you're relocating anyway have you considered posting all the form data to an intermediate PHP file on the server to handle the form data processing, and then redirecting from there? Or posting and handling the form data on `/campaign`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are being caught out by the **asynchronous nature of Ajax**. Ajax does not work in a procedural manner, unfortunately. Your success method is called as and when the Ajax request has completed, which depends on your internet connection speed and how busy the server is.

It is entirely possible, the javascript completes its each loop and the first ajax request is still sending or waiting for a response. By when the javascript is ready to do a window.location call.

**Edit:**

Added code to check the number of forms, and the number of ajax requests, once they have all run, it will redirect

```
$(document).ready(function () {
(function (){
    var id = $(document).data('campaign_id');
    var numForms = $('form').length;
    var numAjaxRequests= 0;

    $(document).on('click', '#save-button', function () {
        $('form').each(function (){
            var data = new FormData(this);
            var form = $(this);
            if(!form.parent().hasClass('hideme'))
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url: form.attr('action'),
                    type: 'POST',
                    data:  data,
                    mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData:false,
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                    {
                        console.log('form submitted '+count);
                        numAjaxRequests++;
                        if(numAjaxRequests == numForms) {
                          window.location.replace('/campaign');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    });
})(); //end SIAF
});//end document.ready
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thanks, I now understand why it was not working as well, forgot the 'a' in ajax...

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, can I ask for you to upvote and accept it, thanks.